# Get the looping selected input value and sum the value inside when it change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple form that loops some select elements from the server. In this case, I want to sum every option value that selected and not the disabled one and show the calculation of these values into the input value every time when the user change the value inside it. How is it work with `onchage` event. Thanks in advance.

**HTML Code Example**

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="number" value="0" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter, Map and reduce

```js
$(function() {
  const sumSels = () => $("#total").val($sels
    .filter(":enabled") // this is not strictly needed in your case
    .map(function() { return +this.value })
    .get()
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    .toFixed(2));

  const $sels = $('[name="presence-value"]');
  $sels.on("change", sumSels); // event handler
  sumSels(); // initialise on load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="number" value="0" readonly id="total">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Version with dynamically added or removed selects

```js
$(function() {
  const sumSels = (e) => $("#total").val(
    $("form").find('[name="presence-value"]')
    .filter(":enabled") // this is not strictly needed in your case
    .map(function() {
      return +this.value
    })
    .get()
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
    .toFixed(2));

  $("form").on("change", "[name='presence-value']", sumSels); // event handler on existing sels
  sumSels(); // initialise on load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input type="number" value="0" readonly id="total">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what if the option is dynamically add/delete?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `document.querySelectorAll('select')` to get all select tags and then by `selectedOptions` get selected value of each select tags and calculate sum of them.

All above actions is in the one method (say `getSum`) that you can bind with `onchange="getSum()"` of each select tag.

Note that this solution is based on pure javascript code and I don't use any js library.

```js
function getSum() {
            var selectes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
            sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < selectes.length; i++) {
                sum += +selectes[i].value;
            }
            document.getElementById("submited").value = sum;
        }
```

```html
<form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required onchange="getSum()">
                <option value="">-- Select--</option>
                <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
                <option value="0.5">Half</option>
                <option value="0">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required onchange="getSum()">
                <option value="">-- Select--</option>
                <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
                <option value="0.5">Half</option>
                <option value="0">None</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required onchange="getSum()">
                <option value="">-- Select--</option>
                <option value="1">Full</option>
                <option value="0.5">Half</option>
                <option value="0" selected>None</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required onchange="getSum()">
                <option value="">-- Select--</option>
                <option value="1">Full</option>
                <option value="0.5">Half</option>
                <option value="0" selected>None</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <input id="submited" type="number" value="0" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `sum += +selectes[i].selectedOptions[0].value;` is the same as `sum += +selectes[i].value;`

Comment: Also selectedOptions is not understood by all browsers

Answer (score 2):

You can just listen to the change event from any of the selects, then add their values together

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    let total = 0;
    $('select').each(function() {
      total += +$(this).val()
    })
    console.log('the total is', total)
    $('[name=total]').val(total)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="1 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1" selected>Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0">None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="2 presence-value form-control" name="presence-value" disabled required>
      <option value="">-- Select--</option>
      <option value="1">Full</option>
      <option value="0.5">Half</option>
      <option value="0" selected>None</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <input name='total' type="number" value="0" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```